# Issue with hidden fields not autofilling correctly in Chrome

Tags: html, css, forms, drop-down-menu, autofill

My dropdown fields use a hidden dropdown field that updates a text input. The reason is because I use a field for 'state' and when a country other than the United States is selected, it turns into the text field that is being updated. There is also a presentation interactive dropdown menu that is separate from the native menu, that uses react to update the hidden dropdown, and the text field. This is all handled using one state through react.

The structure looks like this...

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <input type="hidden" name="state" autocomplete="shipping address-level1">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <i class="icon icon-drop-down" role="presentation"></i>
      ::before <!-- presentation of dropdown that sets the hidden dropdown -->
  </div>
  <select class="hidden">
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
    <option value="AS">American Samoa</option>
    <!-- ... -->
  </select>
</div>
```

Recently Chrome's autofill would not update the hidden select menu. Is this an issue with chrome? Has anyone else experienced this issue? Poking around I've found `display: none` and `visibility: hidden` cause the issue, but making the item visible will enable Chrome's autofill for the dropdown.

Any info would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: I can't find anything that says they've turned this off, but considering all of the security issues about it online, I wouldn't be surprised if they have: https://www.google.com/search?q=chrome+autofill+hidden+fields

Comment: Ya, that's what I'm thinking but I can't find any hard info on it though. I built something locally to test it and it definitely seems like it's been disabled.

Comment: This may shed some light: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=448539